# How can I show an attribute as text with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to show the value of an attribute as text.

```
<div title="12:56pm">
    <span data-measureme="1">

        <span>hi</span>

    </span>
</div>
```

Not working [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLWVm/).

Something like

```
div > span:before {
    content: parent.title;
}
```

Is it possible to do it with CSS? How/why?

About browser compatibility, I only need it to run on latest Chrome and Firefox. But if there is a solution that could work on any browser it would be nice.

Comment: Out of my own curiousity, why don't you use javascript for this?

Comment: @CiaranBaselmans One usage could be for a custom _userstyle_.

Comment: if you put the title on the span then you can get it with attr()

Comment: As of now there's no CSS selector for parent

Comment: He's not trying to select the parent though.

Comment: Your not working fiddle is using a CSS expression, just a remember that CSS expressions work only in IE5-IE7 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a way of using attributes as you're describing in CSS. You'll simply use:

```
content: attr(title);
```

However, the issue you're having in your code is that you can only use this `attr()` function on the element being referenced. In your case, the `span` doesn't have a `title` attribute. You might want to consider reworking your code to allow for something such as:

```
div:before {
    content: attr(title);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn’t this have `div:before`, not `div:after`, to get the intended rendering?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get the parents attribute, but you CAN get its own attributes:

```
<a title="Did this work..? " href="#">Yep, it worked</a>
```

With this CSS:

```
a:before {
  content: attr(title);
}
```

Results in (or showed as...):

```
<a title="Did this work..? " href="#">Did this work..? Yep, it worked</a>
```

Or check my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Milanzor/SxNf9/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 div[title]:after { 
content: attr(title); /* no quotes around attribute name! */
 }
```

IE7 does not support it

Only chance is to use Javascript/Jquery.

[Link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter_content.html)